# traversing Dom in angular

Tags: angular, dom

I'm new in angular, In JavaScript, we can work greate with Dom, we can get element by id, class name, tag name and traverse around the children and parents of the element, but in Angular is this another way do that? or we should use JavaScript core.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: The point of Angular is that it manages it's own DOM, and the Angular lib scripts translates it to actual DOM.

Comment: @AliAzad, the "philosophy" of Angular is to relationate the model (variables in .ts) with the view (how we can see it). You need re-thinking the problems in this terms. e.g. if you want to render a table, you use *ngFor to iterate over an array of object to create the table, NOT get the id of a div and add the elements. Of course you can access to elements of the DOM (It's make using ViewChild and ViewChildren) and use Renderer2 to add elements, but it's not the "angular way"

Comment: You shouldn't even be talking to DOM with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the DOM whit angular structural directives: *ngIf, *ngFor, *ngComponentOutlet etc. see the documentation for examples:https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf
You can get reference from a NODE whit local reference, and `@ViewChild`: https://itnext.io/working-with-angular-5-template-reference-variable-e5aa59fb9af

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

ElementRef gives direct access to DOM in angular. The API used is nativeElement for ex: this.elRef.nativeElement(). But as you can see in the official docs its highly not advisable to use. Try to understand the angular way of doing things by doing some tutorials first. It will help you write more efficient and secure code.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

While you can access the component's DOM by injecting ElementRef, you should avoid it as much as possible. In angular, it provides two-way property binding and bunch of structural directives like ngIf, ngFor or ngSwitch to manipulate DOM based on conditions and list items. You can use ngClass, ngStyle, [class.], [attr.width] etc. syntax to add/remove DOM element's attributes. In general, you will hardly need to directly access the DOM objects from your component's .ts file.